# Software for connection profiles on OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, mac, networking

I'm looking for "connection manager" style software for OS X 10.6 that allows me to create unique profiles for different network connections.  For example, I need a static IP when I'm wired, static IP when wireless at work, and DHCP for other wireless connections.  Is there any software available that meets this need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of built-in through "Locations":

[image: Network locations]

One can also use context-aware software like [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) to select the location automatically.

Comment: This is perfect, worked like a champ.  I was hoping it was as simple as this!

Comment: There is a program called marco polo that can help automate switching connection profiles (you can base it on external information like visible wifi networks, time of day, wall power/battery, etc)

Comment: @skarface, it's actually MarcoPolo (no space in its name) and I mentioned it below the image... :-)

Comment: that's what I get for not actually paying attention. :)  In any event, it's useful software.